# How to point calva/clj-kondo to find the config file in a subrepo, not at root? F ex: /frontend/.clj-kondo/.config

Tags: visual-studio-code, monorepo, vscode-calva, clj-kondo

I'm using a monorepo structure so I don't want it in root, like the documentation wants. So how can I tell calva / clj-kondo where to find this config file?

https://github.com/borkdude/clj-kondo/blob/master/doc/editor-integration.md

Comment: Just for the record, this is a clj-kondo extension thing. Calva bundles clj-kondo, but has no further interaction with it. (That said, of course I, as the Calva maintainer, am interested in getting this to work for you.)

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be resolved in the VSCode clj-kondo extension `2020.5.90`.